# Is there a way to apply a loss function to each output in torch?

Tags: torch

Suppose we have a neural network with multiple outputs, e.g., two nodes in the output layer.
The neural network is trained by back propagating to find the error with the teacher signal.
At this time, we want to find the loss from the loss function for each node and back propagate. The image is that node 1 has error x, node 2 has error y, and so on.
Is there any way to realize this?

Since torch's backward() seems to propagate only scalar values, I got the impression that there is no way to apply a separate error to each node.